# XCode 15 Build error: Stored properties cannot be marked potentially unavailable with '@available'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, react-native, cocoapods

In my react native project I'm using [https://github.com/5-stones/react-native-readium](https://stackoverflow.com).
Because of the dependency R2Streamer i can not run for IOS with XCode 15.

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): /Users/coderythm/workspace/Digilib/bilal/wordr*****/ios/Pods/R2Streamer/Sources/Streamer/Server/PublicationServer.swift:364:6 Stored properties cannot be marked unavailable with '@available'

XCode version : 15.0
pods version : 1.12.1

Despite restarting XCode and the device, updating node_modules and Podfile.lock, and cleaning the project build folder, I haven't been able to resolve the issue.

Comment: This was known to be in the works. Apple had a whole explanation video as to why during WWDC either last year or this year. That sums up to “it was never supposed to work”.

Answer (score 0):

For you to resolve the above-mentioned issue, please run.

> pod update FittedSheets

Answer (score 0):

You can try to update cocoapods to latest version

> gem install cocoapods

Then you can try to `pod install` and build again